Consecutive 3 day push pull leg workout
Is it okay to do a push pull leg workout plan 3 days per week continuously, like Thursday/push, Friday/pull, Saturday/leg, and then the remaining days off?

Why? Surely you can find a way to do 3 full body days per week. Once a week frequency per muscle group simply isn't enough to make meaningful progress. 2x/week is the bare minimum.

what's your goal with this routine?

It is fine if it is what feels good. I personally would split the days so you do not workout like 3 days in a row to 1 day workout 1 day rest etc..., but this is up to you.
I do like having more rest in between the gym days.
